# PIL does not save transparency

Tags: python, png, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('1.png')
img.save('2.png')
```

The first image has a transparent background, but when I save it, the transparency is gone (background is white)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Probably the image is indexed (mode "P" in PIL), so the transparency is not set in PNG alpha channel, but in metadata info.

You can get transparent background palette index with the following code:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('1.png')
png_info = img.info
img.save('2.png', **png_info)
```

image info is a dictionary, so you can inspect it to see the info that it has:

eg: If you print it you will get an output like the following:

```
{'transparency': 7, 'gamma': 0.45454, 'dpi': (72, 72)}
```

The information saved there will vary depending on the tool that created the original PNG, but what is important for you here is the "transparency" key. In the example it says that palette index "7" must be treated as transparent.

Comment: It worked, thank you! Kind of strange, though, that those properties were not saved automatically.

Comment: This issue still occurs with 32bpp transparent images saved from Photoshop `PNG image data, 1063 x 857, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced` so there is definitely an issue with PIL.

Comment: Any idea how this solution can be extended for creating gifs?

Answer (score 7):

You can always force the the type to "RGBA",

```
img = Image.open('1.png')
img = img.convert('RGBA')
img.save('2.png')
```

Comment: Of course, but that way he will not be generating the same image as the original one, from the format wise.

Comment: For the second line you need "img = img.convert('RGBA')".

Answer (score 0):

Also, remember to use formats supporting RGBA. ".jpg" will not work, that's why you have to use ".png"