# PIL Image mode "P" -> "RGBA"

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, converters, mode

This is my issue:

```
import Image
im = Image.open("1.png")
im.show()
print im.mode
im.convert("RGBA").save("2.png")
```

Well, with my image you can see the difference.
My question is: how do I convert it properly?

Image: [image: original]

Result: [image: result]

NOTE: The original image has a semi-transparent glow, the result has a solid green "glow"

Comment: Could you explain what the problem is, perhaps?

Comment: you don't actually say what the difference is.  Is the image you include a before or after?

Comment: Tested it. Did not see any difference. What python and pil version do you use ?

Comment: There is a difference if you open the file outside python, but not between the two img.show()

Comment: What program(s) are you using to display the images?  Can you describe with more detail what is wrong, or provide a screenshot that shows the before and after images?

Comment: Sorry, updated. the problem is the semi-transparency, wich becomes solid. See the added picture

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233772/pil-does-not-save-transparency) Q&A. Read both answers and their comments!

Comment: That was ofcourse the first thing I tried before posting: "im.convert("RGBA").save("BAR2.png", **inf)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1439, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py", line 537, in _save
    raise IOError("cannot use transparency for this mode")
IOError: cannot use transparency for this mode"

Comment: @mDroidd: FWIW the resultant RGBA actually _does_ have an alpha layer that is set to transparency set on exactly the same pixels as those in the palleted image. In other words the "glow" pixels in the palleted image are not marked transparent at all -- which I assume is why they aren't in the RGBA result. I also noted that I see the glow only when I view the image in a browser, but not in the image editor I usually use (Photoshop). This doesn't make sense and I'm trying to figure-out what going on and why.

Comment: Well, for now it seems a suitable option for me to open the image with gdk and save it - that will convert it to RGB without losing partial transparency.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This issue was reported here:

https://bitbucket.org/effbot/pil-2009-raclette/issue/8/corrupting-images-in-palette-mode

In March 2012, a comment says it's now fixed in development version of PIL. The most recent released version is 1.1.7, so the fix won't be available until 1.2 comes out. PIL updates **very** slowly, so don't expect this to come out soon.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately your PNG image is a type that PIL doesn't handle very well - a paletted image with an alpha channel. When you open the image, the alpha is thrown away and there's no way to get it back.

This is different from the usual palette transparency where one index of the palette is used to denote fully transparent pixels.

Comment: Relevant places to look: [PngImagePlugin tRNS loader](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/blob/master/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py#L527-529) where it only reads 1 byte instead of an alpha block, and [PNG tRNS spec](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html#C.tRNS) showing that it should be reading a block, not a single value

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`scipy.misc.imread`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html):

```
img = scipy.misc.imread(filename, mode='RGBA')
img = Image.fromarray(img)
```

Comment: I think this was recently deprecated from scipy without replacement. I'm currently on mobile in vacation, so it's hard to check for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you do not provide info about what PIL should use as source of ALPHA channel.

PIL will not on its own add transparency to your image.

What part of your image you want to be transparent?

Comment: The part that's transparent and/or semi-transparent in the original "P" image :P And auto-detection too, as this is not the only image I need to convert...

Comment: Sorry but for me both images look identical. Can you mark on the 3rd image parts that should be transparent with red?